# powershell script to automate installation of SQL Server 2014 management studio

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, chef-infra

I'm new to power shell and I want to automate the installation of SQL Server 2014 Management Studio on windows server using power shell and need to run remotely using chef cookbook.

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant\Downloads\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU> .\SETUP.EXE /ACTION=install /PARAMETER=true /Q /IACCEPTTHELIC
ENSETERMS=true
Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2014 12.00.2000.08
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The following error occurred:
The setting 'PARAMETER' specified is not recognized.

Error result: -2068578301
Result facility code: 1204
Result error code: 3

Please review the summary.txt log for further details
```

Comment: Venkatesh, I suggest editing the question to describe your efforts so far, focusing on the first specific problem you're having trouble with.

Comment: Hey Erik, Thanks and I done the same your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PARAMETER` in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt) means that you put a parameter there that you want to adjust, not the word "PARAMETER". The parameters are listed in the `Installation Parameters` section.

Comment: Hi James, I have tried using above document and getting the below please check it.It's asking for restart and how can I solve this.Please suggest me... PS C:\Users\vagrant\Downloads\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU> .\SETUP.EXE /QUIET /ACTION="install" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSE
TERMS="true"
Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2014 12.00.2000.08
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The following error occurred:
A computer restart is required. You must restart this computer before installing SQL Server.

Error result: -2067919934
Result facility code: 1214
Result error code: 3010

Comment: You need help in how to restart computer? You really need to try something yourself or at least google

Comment: I tried  in google, not found anything and also used the parameter /RESART=“false” I tried like this also. But error coming..